# Cumsum function step wise in R

Tags: r

I am facing one problem, I calculated a **monthly** interest rate for a mortgage, however, I would need to sum the results in order to have it **yearly** (always 12 months).

```
H <- 2000000 # mortgage
i.m <- 0.03/12 # rate per month
year <- 15 # years

a <- (H*i.m*(1+i.m)^(12*year))/
  ((1+i.m)^(12*year)-1)
a # monthly payment

interest <- a*(1-(1/(1+i.m)^(0:(year*12))))
interest

cumsum(a*(1-(1/(1+i.m)^(0:(year*12))))) # first 12 values together and then next 12 values + first values and ... (I want to have for every year a value)
```

Comment: You would like to sum every 12 values in the last vector? and then cumulative value of first 12 and second 12?

Comment: Yes, every 12 values into one value, but add this value to the next 12 values and till the end of the vector. Let say group by 12 and then cumsum function.

Comment: I want to know how much have I paid on the interest rate every year so far (cumulatively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this with `tapply` in base R.

```
monthly <- cumsum(a*(1-(1/(1+i.m)^(0:(year*12)))))
yearly <- tapply(monthly, ceiling(seq_along(monthly)/12), sum)
```

Comment: Overall interest payment is 486093.9, however your output is ```  4126619.994 4768157.923 5449466.732  486093.905 
 ``` there are numbers over a milion only the last value is correct.

Comment: I want to know how much have I paid on the interest rate every year so far. This is monthly cumsum(a*(1-(1/(1+i.m)^(0:(year*12))))) and I would like to know the same pattern however yearly. (Like keep every 12th value out of this vector). Thank you for help :)

Comment: @JaroslavKotrba Do you mean `monthly[seq(1, length(monthly), 12)]` ?

Comment: Yes this is it, what I was searching for :) thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
monthly <- cumsum(a*(1-(1/(1+i.m)^(0:(year*12)))))

sapply(split(monthly, ceiling(seq_along(monthly) / 12)), function(x) x[length(x)])

         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8 
  2254.446   9334.668  21098.218  37406.855  58126.414  83126.695 112281.337 145467.712 
         9         10         11         12         13         14         15         16 
182566.812 223463.138 268044.605 316202.434 367831.057 422828.023 481093.905 486093.905
```

Comment: It should grow almost lineary, your ending value is 30553936.402 it would mean that at the end I would pay 30 mil on rate only by 2 mil mortgage.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your desired output. I summed your `monthly` vector values for spans of `12` and then accumulate the result. What would you like me do instead?

Comment: I want to know how much have I paid on the interest rate every year so far. This is monthly cumsum(a*(1-(1/(1+i.m)^(0:(year*12))))) and I would like to know the same pattern however yearly. (Like keep every 12th value out of this vector). Thank you for help :)

Comment: Do you know how to take every 12th value from this vector?

Comment: Oh 12th value you mean? or vectors of length 12? I got where the problem is I think. Because in your question you specified first 12 values, which is different than every 12th value.

Comment: @JaroslavKotrba see my edit please to see whether it's what you have in mind.

Comment: Yes this is it, what I was searching for :) thank you very much :) I would accept both solutions ;)